# Word.Range.TextVisibleOnScreen?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Does the Word.Range.TextVisibleOnScreen property actually work?

```
Private Sub isVisTest()
  Dim rng As Range: Set rng = oDoc.Bookmarks("_Toc#########").Range
  'replace ######### with a good Heading bookmark number from your test document
  Dim c As Integer

  ActiveWindow.VerticalPercentScrolled = 0
  ActiveWindow.HorizontalPercentScrolled = 0
  oDoc.ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView rng
  Do
    oDoc.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
Debug.Print rng.TextVisibleOnScreen
    c = c + 1
    If c > 10 Then Exit Do
  Loop Until rng.TextVisibleOnScreen = 0
  oDoc.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Up:=6
End Sub
```

The abbreviated procedure uses Heading bookmark to display the corresponding Heading at the top of the screen simto Word's built-in Nav Pane behavior. The Do-Loop is a refinement to bring the Heading to top of page but I'm finding that the rng.TextVisibleOnScreen property never changes regardless of whether the rng object is actually visible onscreen or not; it's always -1. Thus the property seems disabled. However, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/range-textvisibleonscreen-property-word) doesn't report it as being disabled or deprecated.

The same test can be done by using a Selection and the IDE's Immediate window, i.e., ?Selection.Range.TextVisibleOnScreen. I get the same result; always -1.

Comment: This is a new property - I'd never seen it before. From the documentation: "Text that is not visible could be, for example, text that is in a collapsed heading." Possibly, this has more to do with "hidden" text than whether something is scrolled to be visible? Try the `ScrollIntoView` method.

Comment: Hi Cindy, the ScrollintoView is already in the proc.
What does "new" mean? This property dates back several generations of Office.
What were your results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As implied by the [language reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/range-textvisibleonscreen-property-word?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> The TextVisibleOnScreen property returns 1 if all text in the range is
>   visible; it returns 0 if no text in the range is visible; and it
>   returns -1 if some text in the range is visible and some is not. Text
>   that is not visible could be, for example, text that is in a collapsed
>   heading.

this property lets you know whether a `Range` is visible or not due to a Heading style being collapsed or expanded. The capability to collapse/expand sections of text under a heading was introduced at the same time - in Word 2013.

It has nothing to do whether text is hidden or scrolled off the screen.

What is definitely odd / misleading is the statement that 1 is returned when something is visible and -1 when something is only partially visible. I believe this is a mistake in the documentation, possibly from the 2013 beta that never was corrected.

The following code returns 0 when the range (second paragraph in the document) is not visible because a heading style before it is collapsed:

```
Sub TestHiddenText
  Dim rng as Word.Range

  Set rng = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(3).Range
  Debug.Print rng.TextVisibleOnScreen
End Sub
```

When the heading is expanded, the above returns -1 (which traditionally has always been "true" in Word).

If I collapse that heading, but test the entire document, the mixed status returns what I'd expect from Word - undefined: 9999999

```
Sub TestHiddenText
  Dim rng as Word.Range

  Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
  Debug.Print rng.TextVisibleOnScreen
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting! When I run the test using Selection from the immediate pane of my 2007 version it produces no error which 'seems' to indicate that the engine recognizes the property. I'll re-run it again this evening to verify both that and to additionally test the collapsed heading condition.
In any case, it appears that it does not serve the function that I had thought it would; that is, that the range is actually visible on the screen. Ah, but what's in a name "TextVisibleOnScreen"?

Oh and lest I forget, TY Cindy!

Comment: Hmm, I've confirmed Cindy's test results. A range assigned to a variable will produce -1 if NOT collapsed within it's parent heading. It will produce 0 when it IS collapsed within its parent heading.