# Range TextVisibleOnScreen always return -1

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, netoffice

I am using the following code to find some strings in my document:

```
Application application = Addin.Application;
Document document = application.ActiveDocument;
Range rng = document.Content;

rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
rng.Find.Forward = true;
rng.Find.Text = findText;

while (rng.Find.Execute() && rng.Find.Found)
{
    // here this is always rng.TextVisibleOnScreen == -1
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.textvisibleonscreen):

> The TextVisibleOnScreen property returns 1 if all text in the range is
>   visible; it returns 0 if no text in the range is visible; and it
>   returns -1 if some text in the range is visible and some is not. Text
>   that is not visible could be, for example, text that is in a collapsed
>   heading.

However the property is always `-1` even when the text is not on the screen at all or when all the text is on the screen... Is this a known issue? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This has been asked before, please see  [Word.Range.TextVisibleOnScreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821429/word-range-textvisibleonscreen)

Comment: @CindyMeister - it kind of has, but it is a VBA question rather than VSTO / netoffice...